# Can a post be lost while rotating screen?

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

Is that possible that when I click the button and then after waiting some time (~5sec) rotate the screen the post may be missed, because the activity didn't manage to re-register in time?
I believe that I've managed to produce that. But it was like 1 from 50 tries:)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.post)
    Button mPost;

    @BindView(R.id.result)
    TextView mResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.post)
    void onPostClick() {

        HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyThread");
        handlerThread.start();
        Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.e(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new MyObject("wow"));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onResult(MyObject object) {
        Log.e(TAG, "POST " + object);
    }

    static class MyObject {
        String val;

        public MyObject(String val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return val;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course. Because the Activity is restarted. This is the ABC of Android programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a chance Activity code miss the event due to recreation, however if this is a problem then you most likely should be posting your events as `sticky`:

> Some events carry information that is of interest after the event is
>   posted. For example, an event signals that some initialization is
>   complete. Or if you have some sensor or location data and you want to
>   hold on the most recent values. Instead of implementing your own
>   caching, you can use sticky events. EventBus keeps the last sticky
>   event of a certain type in memory. The sticky event can be delivered
>   to subscribers or queried explicitly. Thus, you don’t need any special
>   logic to consider already available data.

http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/

Also, some suggests moving registration handling from `onStart`/`onStop` to `onCreate`/`onDestroy`. I think is is bad idea - you usually do not care the events if you are in background, therefore I'd also recommend moving reg/unreg code to `onResume`/`onPause` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity gets recreate while you rotate your device. You can set manifest attribute like. `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

Comment: It's a little bit hacky.

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is recreate your activity using onSaveInstanceState() method.

**Save Your Activity State**

```
static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";
...

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Save the user's current game state
savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

// Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

**Restore Your Activity State**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first

// Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    // Restore value of members from saved state
    mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
    mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
} else {
    // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
}
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to subsribe/unsubscribe the listener not in `onStart` and `onStop`, but in `onCreate` and `onDestroy` resp. Also, post the event in `main` thread. In this case there won't be the gap and new activity will receive the event if recteated

Comment: Thanks. I see my mistake. I will add @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN).